# Prometheus: invalid hostname with https scheme

Tags: prometheus

prometheus is telling me that:

> "https://some-domain.com/backoffice" is not a valid hostname"

My config file is:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring_micrometer'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
            - targets: ['192.168.99.102:8085', '192.168.99.102:8083', '192.168.99.102:8084', 'https://<domain>/backoffice']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

As Gaurav said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59883214/5519270), we can only use the [host](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#host) type (`<domain>`) in the `targets` array. In order to incorporate the https `scheme` and the path `/backoffice`, you need to use `scheme` and `metric_path` properties respectively in the configuration (`scheme` defaults to `http` and metric_path to `/metrics` if not mentioned explicitly).

I see that you have already added the `metric_path:'/actuator/prometheus'` which is shared among other `targets`. Therefore, you might need to create different scrape job for the one having a different `metric_path` and `scheme` as shown here:

```
  - job_name: 'spring_micrometer_2'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: "/backoffice/actuator/prometheus"
    scheme: "https"
    static_configs:
      - targets:<domain>
```

If you want to have same job name "spring_micrometer" on all the targets, you can make use of [`relabel_configs`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) as shown below on the "spring_micrometer_2" job:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring_micrometer'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
            - targets: ['192.168.99.102:8085', '192.168.99.102:8083', '192.168.99.102:8084']
  - job_name: 'spring_micrometer_2'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: "/backoffice/actuator/prometheus"
    scheme: "https"
    static_configs:
      - targets:<domain>
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [job]
        target_label:  job
        replacement:   `spring_micrometer`
```

Answer (score 4):

Static Configs targets need to be a valid string consisting of a hostname or IP followed by an optional port number.

The valid hostname here would be `<domain>` not `https://<domain>/backoffice`

For reference, you can check below 
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#host

And for checking whether the hostname is valid check the following regex test
https://www.regextester.com/23